# How to pass values from one thread to another thread Python?

Tags: python-3.x, gpio, raspberry-pi4

**I begin to code the python and I am not have more experience in syntax of python**

1. I want to send a value from the RFID reader. If it saves successfully, the PIR Motion Sensor will be disabled in a moment. and reworking within the specified time.
2. If the temperature is measured And send the value to the function RFID Reader to record the temperature and the PIR Motion Sensor stops working as well.

```
    class Security:

        global dbHost
        global dbUser
        global dbPass
        global dbNameEmp
        global dbNameSecure
        dbHost = 'localhost'
        dbUser = 'root'
        dbPass = 'iTdev#2020'

        dbNameEmp = 'empinfo'
        dbNameSecure = 'secureinfo'

        def __init__(self):
            self.msg=""

        def Temperature(self):
            while True:
        
                GPIO.output(TRIG, False)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                GPIO.output(TRIG, True)
                time.sleep(0.01)
                GPIO.output(TRIG, False)

                while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 0 :
                    pulse_start = time.time()

                while GPIO.input(ECHO) == 1 :
                    pulse_end = time.time()

                pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
                distance = pulse_duration * 11150
                distance = round(distance,2)

                if distance > 0 and distance < 3 :

                    buzzer.on()
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    buzzer.off()
                    print ("Distance: %scm" % (distance))
                    #print "Ambient Temperature :", sensor.get_ambient()
                    print ("Temperature: %.1fc" % (sensor.get_object_1()))

                    msgTemp = ("%.1f" % (sensor.get_object_1()))
                    w, h = textsize(msgTemp, font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
                    if w <= device.width:
                        x = round((device.width - w) / 2)
                        with canvas(device) as draw:
                            text(draw, (x, 0), msgTemp, fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
                    else:
                        show_message(device, msgTemp, fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT),scroll_delay=0.04)

                    time.sleep(1)
                    device.clear()

        def rfid_callback(self, state, dev):

            rfid_presented = ""
            keys = "X^1234567890XXXXqwertzuiopXXXXasdfghjklXXXXXyxcvbnmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            while True:
                r,w,x = select([dev], [], [])
                for event in dev.read():
                    if event.type==1 and event.value==1:
                        if event.code==28:

                            rfid_presented = rfid_presented.replace("X", "")
                            travel = state.replace("Thread-", "")

                            dbConnEmp = mysql.connect(host=dbHost, user=dbUser, passwd=dbPass, db=dbNameEmp)
                            curEmp = dbConnEmp.cursor()
                            curEmp.execute("Select RFidEmp FROM RFidMaster WHERE (RFidStatus = 1) AND RFidNumber = '%s'" % (rfid_presented))
                            resultRFid = curEmp.fetchone()
                            if curEmp.rowcount != 1:
                                # print("Access Denied." + travel)
                                with canvas(device) as draw:
                                    text(draw, (0, 0), "None", fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
                                time.sleep(0.5)
                                device.clear()
                            else:
                                # print("Unlocking Door." + travel)
                                dbConnSecure = mysql.connect(host=dbHost, user=dbUser, passwd=dbPass, db=dbNameSecure)
                                curSecure = dbConnSecure.cursor()
                                curSecure.execute("SELECT EntraId,DATE_FORMAT(CreateDate, '%Y%m%d') AS CreateDate FROM entranlog ORDER BY EntraId DESC, CreateDate DESC LIMIT 1")
                                resultKey = curSecure.fetchone()
                                KeyDate = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
                                if curSecure.rowcount != 1:
                                    KeyId = KeyDate+"0001"
                                else:
                                    if resultKey[1] == KeyDate:
                                        iSum = int(resultKey[0])
                                        def sum(x, y):
                                            return x + y
                                        KeyId = ('%d' % sum(iSum, 1))
                                    else:
                                        KeyId = KeyDate+"0001"

                                create_date = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
                                insertSecure = "INSERT INTO entranlog (EntraId,EntraAction,EntraStatus,CreateBy,CreateDate) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                                valSecure = (KeyId,travel,1,resultRFid[0],create_date)
                                curSecure.execute(insertSecure, valSecure)
                                dbConnSecure.commit()
                                # print("Welcome: " + resultRFid[0])
                                with canvas(device) as draw:
                                    text(draw, (0, 0), "Hello", fill="white", font=proportional(CP437_FONT))
                                print(curSecure.rowcount, "record inserted.")

                                time.sleep(0.8)
                                device.clear()

                            rfid_presented = ""
                        else:
                            rfid_presented += keys[ event.code ]


        def PirSensor(self):
            while True:
                led_blue.on()
                time.sleep(0.1)
                current_state = GPIO.input(pir_sensor)
                if current_state == 1:
                    print("GPIO pin %s is %s" % (pir_sensor, current_state))
                    GPIO.output(relay_alarm,True)
                    led_blue.off()
                    led_red.blink(0.1, 0.2)
                    # buzzer.beep(0.5, 0.5, 3)
                    time.sleep(5)

                    GPIO.output(relay_alarm,False)

                    led_red.off()
                    led_yellow.blink(0.5, 0.5)
                    time.sleep(5)
                    led_yellow.off()

        def main(self):

            devIn = threading.Thread(target=self.rfid_callback, args=['1', InputDevice('/dev/input/event0')])
            devIn.start()
            devOut = threading.Thread(target=self.rfid_callback, args=['2', InputDevice('/dev/input/event1')])
            devOut.start()

            Pir = threading.Thread(target=self.PirSensor)
            Pir.start()

            Temp = threading.Thread(target=self.Temperature)
            Temp.start()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        g=Security()
        g.main()
```

Comment: the safest way to send data from one thread to another is to use a Queue from the queue library. To do this, create a Queue instance that is shared by the threads. Threads then use put() or get() operations to add or remove items from the queue as shown in the code given below.

Comment: Can you give an example, eg stop def Prsensor?

Comment: see [Queue – A thread-safe FIFO implementatio](https://pymotw.com/2/Queue/)